# Handle umlauts in file names when using xarg

Tags: bash, xargs, special-characters

I've seen some similar questions here where people have problems with `xargs` handling spaces in file names. Surprisingly, I don't run into this issue, but a similar one.

I'm copying a fixed amount of files (which are chosen randomly in a very messy manner) from a large pool of files. The line of code looks as follows:

`find "/path/to/source/dir" -size +1k -type f -print0 | sort -R | ghead -z -n 10 | xargs -0 -I{} cp "{}" "/path/to/destination/dir"`

Think of it like drawing winners in a raffle, as each file is named after a person. Since some of the drawn people happen to be German they may also have very German names like Matthäus Müller. (Other special characters aren't to be considered.)

Every time this monster of code draws a person with umlauts in their name (or more precise, in the file name) the copy process stops with:

`cp: /path/to/source/dir/Matthäus Müller.jpg: No such file or directory`

I can assure this issue is not because of the space character, as all file names have spaces and it only interrupts on one with umlauts.

Is there anything to fix this or do I have to write that whole mechanism in a different way (if so, what's the way to go)?

Note 1: I cannot change those file names to "Matthaeus Mueller.jpg" or something like that to circumvent this issue; they are as they are.

Note 2: In case this is important, the script is running on macOS.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the `-z` for NULL-terminated records from `sort`. Fix that and the problem goes away (for me, anyway). It's odds whether or not you manage to copy the name with umlauts - I don't think that's actually the issue.

Example

```
mkdir /tmp/610423/{src,dst}
cd /tmp/610423
touch 'src/Matthäus Müller.jpg' 'src/Peter Gurney' 'src/Tom Pearce'

# Error here
find /tmp/610423/src -type f -print0 | sort -R | head -zn10 | xargs -0 -I{} cp {} dst/
cp: cannot stat ''$'\n': No such file or directory

# No error here
find /tmp/610423/src -type f -print0 | sort -zR | head -zn10 | xargs -0 -I{} cp {} dst/
```

I've tested on a Debian Linux distribution. I assume your `ghead` is the GNU `head` program that we have as standard on Debian. Does your `sort` have `-z`? If not you might need to rethink the `-print0` carried through the rest of the utilities, nice though it is.